# zookeeper.znode.parent value for standalone mode

Tags: hbase, config, apache-zookeeper

I am running HBase in standalone mode, and getting the below error.

```
2016-10-05 16:29:06,268 ERROR [main] client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper

It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
```

What shall be the value of zookeeper.znode.parent for Standalone mode for HBase in HBase-site.xml file ?

Comment: can you pls show your ```hbase-site.xml```, the default value of ```zookeeper.znode.parent``` is ```/hbase```, it seems ok to me.

Comment: `<configuration>`
`<property>`
`<name>hbase.rootdir</name>`
`<value>/Users/tcssig/Downloads/hbase-1.0.3</value>`
 `</property>`
  `<property>`
   `<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>`
    `<value>/Users/tcssig/Downloads/zookeeper-3.4.9</value>`
  `</property>`
  `<property>`
    `<name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>`
   `<value>false</value>`
  `</property>`
  `<property>`
  `</configuration>`

Comment: Above is the hbase-site.xml file which I used.

Answer (score 0):

Need to check the HBase logs and then proceed for solution.

Please refer to the post below for troubleshooting the error.

https://sarangmanjrekar.wordpress.com/2016/10/06/node-hbase-is-not-in-zookeeper/

Answer (score 0):

Best solution you can get from HBase logs. In my case i was running Kafka + zookeeper and HBase on the same server. So, whenever i was trying to run hbase shell i was kept getting same error on the console. When I checked logs and found

> port is already in use

so i just changed port number for the zookeeper in hbase-site.xml file and everything start running.